# Grub modify menu screen [ advanced ]

Tags: linux, grub2, grub

I've modified my Grub menu. Here is how it looks like right now:
[image]

What I would like is to remove the top information about Grub version or even better to remove all "**GNU GRUB version 1.99-27.1crunchbang1**".

Additionally, it would be great to remove the bottom information about using the arrow keys to move within menu, and how to edit entries.

To summarize - i want to get rid of text highlighted in red:

[image]

1. Is it possible?
2. Is it possible without modifying the source code of
   Grub?

I must admit I've searched for a good couple of hours in the web how to do it, but all i've got is how to do basic modifications within grub.
I will appreciate any help or even a hint where to look next to a clue.

Comment: GRUB customizer looks like it might give you what you want: https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer. This thread too looked useful: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10340183#post10340183 in addition to this resource: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275

Comment: @slm Thanks. That is a lot of collected knowledge on the subject. Sadly i haven't found any information how to remove mentioned text. Grub customizer is helpful but it can do only what i have already done manually.

Comment: OK, sorry didn't help you out. I didn't see anything further than that, so you might be relegated to the source option. I think I'd ask you Q on the GRUB mailing list instead: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/help-grub

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the current installation's header or footer.  This is because those functions are inside the source code of Grub.  What you can do is compile grub from source, which will give you access to the C files, where these functions exist.  I will attempt to provide a guide on how to do this using something from a different SE.

---

I am going to provide a caveat.  ***Test this in a virtual machine or in a crash & burn environment to make sure it all works.  This way, you do not screw up your Grub install (in case something goes wrong).***

---

**1)** You will need to download the flavor of Grub you want from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grub/.  I suggest you stick with the version Crunchbang uses (1.99) in case there are any conflicts with newer versions.  You could also do this by getting the source code from where ever your packages come from for their version of grub, but it is up to you. To do this, you can do:

```
mkdir ~/srccode && cd ~/srccode
sudo apt-get source grub2
```

The `mkdir` is to help in file management (i.e. to keep it away from all your other files).  Either way, the process is going to be similar, but I think the latter is easier.

**2)** Next you are going to need the build dependencies, and there is a nice little list of them. You can install all of these dependencies by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential bison gettext binutils flex libdevmapper-dev
python autoconf automake autogen qemu quilt
```

The above command can be somewhat shortened if you use the method 2 from above:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential quilt
sudo apt-get build-dep grub2
```

**3)** Export variables and set up quilt:

```
export QUILT_PATCHES=debian/patches

export EDITOR=gedit
```

**4)** Create your patch and edit the source

```
cd grub2-{version}
quilt new 99_custom-header-footer.patch
quilt edit grub-core/normal/main.c
```

[image: main.c]

You are going to want to change the highlighted line to:

```
const char *msg = _(" ");
```

You also need to:

```
quilt edit grub-core/normal/menu_text.c
```

[image: menu_text.c]

And similarly change all highlighted sections so that everything between the double quotes is:

```
(some code)..." "...(some more code)
```

similarly to the previous example.

**5)** Pray to your chosen deity and build the deb packages

```
quilt refresh
fakeroot dpkg-buildpackage
```

**6)** Offer a sacrifice to your deity (I usually use the blood of the innocent, but I am sure some transistors will do) and install the packages you created

```
cd ..
sudo dpkg -i grub-pc*.deb grub2-common*.deb
```

**7)** Consider handing over your firstborn and restart your machine.  If everything worked out, you should get the changes you desired.  I have only done editting of grub like this a handful of times (a very tiny handful), but this process (and the original link I provided) are similar in the way I accomplished it.

Comment: Can you incorporate some of the info from that Q&A here? Generally the various SE sites like to be "free standing" and contain the gist of content that is referenced in links vs. just providing a link.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me.  I sometimes forget which SE I am on at any given time (it's almost like a blur).

Comment: @ChrisR. Thank you very much for your answer. It looks very promissing. I will try that in a VM (as you suggested) during the weekend and if everything will go as expected I will mark your answer as accepted on Monday. Thank you once again.